# returning Boolean values

Tags: c#, c++, boolean

I have a piece of code which is to be converted to c#.

```
bool checkvalue()
{
unsigned char ucvalue;
Method(&ucvalue);
return ucvalue? false:true;
}
```

the Method() has the definition  :

```
This function returns the current position . 0 = OFF 1 = ON
```

So I didn't get what `return ucvalue? false:true;` means.

Thanks.

Comment: It is the [ternary or condiitonal operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: By the way, that operator is also present in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the `ternary-operator`, you can "translate" this expression almost 1:1 to C#. It is the same like

```
if(ucvalue)
   return false;
return true;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for C#:

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

From [here](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/looping/operator2.htm) for C++:

> You can exchange simple if-else code for a single operator – the conditional operator.  The conditional operator is the only C++ ternary operator (working on three values).  Other operators you have seen are called binary operators (working on two values).

Comment: is this condition make any idea?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `return ucvalue? false:true;`

Comment: I simply assume that you ask me, if this is common to use the ternary operator? Well, there are certain times, when you want to use it. Mainly, if you want to express `if/else` in a single line or you need only a simple `if/else`-statement at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to:

```
return ucvalue==0;
```

which I find the most attractive form. I would perhaps change Method() so that it return the value instead of taking an argument. That will make the code simpler:

```
return Method()==0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd presume it means "if ucvalue is null, return false, else return true"

Comment: Wrong. It means `if ucvalue is NOT null, return false, else return true`

Comment: seems like I can't minus myself 8)